# optimize and best practice for image call each time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have client code for large project, their logo is on master page, which he updates weekly.

I have to update the title, image path, etc. on all the server and also upload a new image on all servers, now he wants to automate this process.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I have thought about storing the information (including Image) in database with single record and each time client update this single record when they want. But on each page, the logo image will come from database. Is it ok or should we cache or some other option to reduce load each time? Can we update page(.aspx) file using filestream like we can update text file? because if I update aspx from code then we don't have call any SQL, just upload an image, update the title and other information in aspx page.

Comment: Why not turn the entire logo + text into a static HTML file with static image suitable for including in other pages when necessary?  You could even create a management page that lets the user type in a few lines of text and upload an image to create it.  (just need file/write access to the folder from web-app)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. If the client wants to update something on their own without requiring developer intervention, it needs to go in the database. You can of course add any caching or whatever you like so that it's not necessary to query the database each request.

The only other viable alternative would be giving the client access to the directory that has the logo and insist on a convention for the logo filename. The client can then simply upload a new logo with the same filename and nothing needs to change on the site.

Making changes to the page itself automatically is a hugely bad idea. Avoid that like the plague.

I suppose a final though not bloody likely option is to get the client to realize that a logo shouldn't freaking be changed weekly or even yearly. It's a freaking *logo*; it's your identifying mark to the public.

Comment: "insist on a convention for the logo filename" - Or look for the most recent image in the folder and choose that.  Or have a page that chooses the filename to load from dir listing of that folder etc...

Comment: "most recent" doesn't necessarily mean it will be the right logo or even a logo at all. It could be some other image used on the site was changed more recently. And, in fact any foolproof method of determining what image to use from the filesystem will require *some sort of convention* to work. Besides, querying the filesystem at runtime is all sorts of evil, if you don't explicitly need to.

Comment: hence the need for a specific /logos/ folder or something like it.  (poll early, poll infrequently maybe every 10 minutes?  Or heck, have a "poll now" button)

Comment: You're still talking about storing that information for later, which requires a database query. The only way to avoid persisting the explicit choice of image would be to enact conventions that would allow the app to automatically select the right file from the filesystem.

Comment: latest time/date certainly doesn't need DB, cache it in memory on start-up.  User selection would, of course, require some kind of storage.  But, that could be keeping a backup copy and writing to just one unchanging static file name set.  e.g. logo.jpg, fortune.txt